# Mysql / Hql running total needs single result but cannot get due to subselect limitation

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am using a running total to find the median of a weighted set.  This works fine in sql, but not in hql due to Hibernate not supporting subselects in the FROM clause.  I cannot easily drop to sql because the actual code involves a lot of dynamic query building already in place in hql.

Here's the sample table:

```
score  weight
2      1
5      1
5      1
6      1
7      1
10     2
10     2
```

The total scores are 9 (I know this before this query).  9/2 = 4.5, so this query should return 6 as the weighted median score.

Here's the sample query:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT 
    q1.score
FROM
    (SELECT 
        score, (@runtot:=@runtot + weight) AS rt
    FROM
        tmp_stddev
    ORDER BY score) as q1
WHERE
    q1.rt <= (9 / 2)
ORDER BY q1.score DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Ordering by the score ASC in the subselect enables me to keep adding weights until I get to the halfway point.  Ordering DESC in the outer query enables me to use the LIMIT to return just the single result for best performance (there can be a lot of data here, so I really only want to return one result).

This works in SQL, but not in HQL.  I can create a custom dialect I believe to support the setting of the user variable inside the query (the clearing it to 0 part would be in a separate sql query against the same connection).  The problem is the subselect.

I could do this:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SET @runtot2:=0;

SELECT
    score,
   (@runtot := @runtot + weight) AS rt
FROM
    tmp_stddev
WHERE (@runtot2 := @runtot2 + weight) <= (9/2)
ORDER BY score;
```

but this would return me all the scores, and I really just want the one (the dataset can be very large and speed is important).

Any suggestions how to re-write this to return a single result, be fast, and be in a form of sql that hql can generate?

UPDATE:
Based on Mosty Mostacho's suggestions below, and some other research, this seems to work consistently:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT 
    score, weight, @val := score
FROM 
    tmp_stddev
WHERE
    (@runtot := @runtot + weight) <= (9 / 2)
ORDER BY score;
```

Here by selecting the last matched score into a variable, I can use it later in the same connection by selecting it's value, and get the last item in the sort list, which is what I want.  Also, I have reduced the scope of the read/write for the User Defined variable, that seemed to be inconsistent when I changed the data around.

Questions:

- Is this a safe usage of User Defined variables?  I've been reading a lot about how unsafe it is to read/write them in the same statement, but doesn't this have to evaluate in order since the read/write are both part of a single expression in the HAVING clause?  In other words, is this reliable?
- How can I get this to work in HQL?  If I use a Custom Dialect and create a custom function that does the '@val := score' portion, I get an 'Invalid filter-parameter name format' exception (I think because of the colon, but shouldn't that just be a direct pass-through substitution from the HQL to the SQL by Hibernate?  Why would it care that there's a colon?)
- Are there any better solutions that my query above that I haven't considered?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear... because the running total is 4 by the time it gets to 6, and 5 once the score is 7, it should pick the row with the score of 6.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think I've just realized how it worked: You've truncated the number `4.5` which results in just `4`and then took the fourth element from top to bottom (which happens to be with weight `1` so it really is the fourth element in the column)

Comment: Well... it uses <=, and it's important that it doesn't round (my first table did b/c I had defined weight as an INT) - the real table uses fractional scores.  So 4 <= 4.5, that gets us a set from scores 2..6

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got absolutely lost in the math :)

Anyway, I tried to turn your first query into something that doesn't use the `FROM` clause that way. This is what I got:

```
SELECT score, (@runtot := @runtot + weight) rt
FROM t, (SELECT @runtot := 0) init
HAVING rt = FLOOR(9 / 2)
ORDER BY score
```

Using the `having` clause that way is really a mess but it seems the only way not to need a derived table in there. The only issue is that, although this would answer this question it won't help you with a decimal field.

Now, the solution might not be as simple as changing the `having` clause into

```
HAVING rt <= 9 / 2
```

Check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3852f/1) to see how that messes with the results. That's what you make when you mess with User Defined Variables and don't user a derived table.

The second thing to try is if you can have a derived table in a `JOIN`. I mean:

```
SELECT * FROM t
JOIN (
  SELECT id FROM r
) s ON t.id = s.id
```

This is how far I can get but probably gave you a couple of ideas to try :)

**Edit (last try):**

After the following query I'll have to ask for forgiveness to the SQL language:

```
SELECT score
FROM t, (SELECT @runtot := 0.0) init
WHERE (@runtot := @runtot + weight) AND (9 / 2 >= @runtot)
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85ba9/1).

Comment: Well, I tried HAVING earlier b/c I hoped that would work... but the results got wacky.  I'm not sure Hibernate would support the second syntax... according to the doc, you can only have sub-selects in the select or where clause.  I suppose I could convert the scoring to Integer-based... that's a possibility.

Comment: Hmmm... nice... that might do it!  Well, I tried some different values, and now not getting it...I put some large weights in the top part of the range (like setting the weight on 10 to 5), and it's still getting 6 as the result... not sure why.

Comment: Rats, the manual says:  As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.

Comment: Yes, I know. But in practice you can do it. In there you'll see the explanation why `having` is not working as expected too.

Comment: But it doesn't seem to be working right when I changed the data.  When I added weight to the higher values (a weight of 5 for one of the 10's), it should have resulted in 10 being the answer.

Comment: I mean, if you have 2 `select` (one inside a `from` clause) then that is one statement too. You can use the value from inner statement in your outer statement (as you do in your question). So in those cases it is safe. Try playing with indexes too. Create the index `alter table t add index(score, weight)`. That usually changes the results you get and you should try all the options again. Anyway, that's close to hacking mysql :)